# flash content not works only firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

[http://www.мультипак.org/lib/Multi_Pack/bin/](http://www.%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA.org/lib/Multi_Pack/bin/)

This flash works everywhere (opera, chrome, safari), but when I open with firefox flash not work after 100%, 
(but work in localhost)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Multi_Puck</title>
 <meta name="description" content="" />

 <script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
 <script>
  var flashvars = {
  };
  var params = {
   menu: "false",
   scale: "noScale",
   allowFullscreen: "true",
   allowScriptAccess: "always",
   wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
  };
  var attributes = {
   id:"MultiPuck"
  };
  swfobject.embedSWF(
   "MultiPuck.swf", 
   "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", 
   "expressInstall.swf", 
   flashvars, params, attributes);
 </script>
 <style>
  html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
  body { margin:0; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="altContent">
  <h1>Multi_Puck</h1>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I opened your page with flash player debug version on firefox, I got this security error (only on firefox) :

```
#2044: Unhandled securityError : text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation : http://www.мультипак.org/lib/Multi_Pack/bin/MultiPuck.swf cannot load data from config.xml.
    at _XML_/loadXml()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\_XML_.as:34]
    at _XML_()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\_XML_.as:29]
    at Main/init()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\Main.as:61]
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at Preloader/startup()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\Preloader.as:105]
    at Preloader/loadingFinished()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\Preloader.as:99]
    at Preloader/checkFrame()[xxxxxxxxxxxx\Downloads\Multi_Puck\src\Preloader.as:85]
```

I changed your local path with 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'.

Try to add a `crossdomain.xml` and force loading it using :

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.мультипак.org/crossdomain.xml")
```

For more info about `crossdomain.xml`, take a look here : [Adobe : Cross-domain policy for Flash movies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

To debug your online prod version in your browser, you can download and install flash player debug version here : [FlashPlayer downloads](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

I hope all this helps you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

only use absolute paths or local paths only, should not combine. That is the reason that it shows the security error